# Saving textbox suggestions/autocomplete when submitting form via AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a basic form that is shown inside of a dialog. I'm using an `Ajax.BeginForm` to submit the form when the dialog is closed (a non-MVC example of the dialog is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsjkk/)). Therefore the form is not actually *submitted*.

When I submit this form via ajax and then refresh and type a value, the previously typed values aren't show (as if the form wasn't submitted - which makes sense).

However, I'd like the user to have their previously entered values display when they begin to type in the textbox. Is there any way (other than saving the values to the DB!) to get the browser to autocomplete previous textbox values?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-autocomplete

You should only set the attribute autocomplete to "on".

http://jsfiddle.net/94CMP/

Comment: If autocomplete is omitted, it's [default state is on](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete-on-state).

Comment: Well, I have no idea then. It should be working just by default eitherway.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't change anything except the autocomplete attribute to "on", this is redundant since the default value is "on". Additionally, that sample *works* because the form is actually posted.

Comment: Well it does sort of make sense... the *form* isn't actually submitted.

Comment: I was thinking he was unfortunate enough to be using IE and IE wouldn't use the default.